Error en migración de Entity Framework despues de actulizar la versión de .NET de 6.0 a 8.0
Estoy teniendo un problema al crear una nuea migración de entity framework despues de actualizar la versión de dotnet de 6.0 a 8.0.
Tengo un proyecto con .net6.0 donde hago uso de las migraciónes de entity framework. Después de actualizar la versión de .net de 6.0 a 8.0 e intentar crear una nueva migración de base de datos con EF obtengo el siguiente error:
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Active

Este error parece estár relacionado con una de las entidades en mi aplicación.
Tengo 2 clases base llamadas 'BaseModel' y 'BaseModelActive' de las cuales heredan el resto de las entidades de mi aplicación, el contenido de mis entidades base es el siguiente:
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = "admin@connectupweb.com";
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseModelActive : BaseModel
{
    public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
}

Estás clase base NO se mapean a la base de datos, simplemente son unas clases auxiliares que me permiten gestionar las propiedades en común que van a tener el resto de las entidades que si se mapean a la base de datos, por ejemplo:
public sealed class Advertisement : BaseModelActive
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EventStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EventEndDate { get; set; }

    public AdvertisementFile AdvertisementFile { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AdvertisementReaction> Reactions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AdvertisementComment> Comments { get; set; }
}

Se puede observar que en la clase base 'BaseModelActive' se tiene una propiedad llamada 'Active' que me permite saber si un registro de base de datos se encuentra activo o no en la plataforma, y parece ser esta misma propiedad la que genera un conflicto al intentar crear una nueva migración de EF.
he revisado las configuraciones de mis entidades para asegurarme de que ninguna de ellas esté sobreescribiendo la propiedad 'Active' definida en 'BaseModelActive' por lo tanto estoy seguro que ninguna de las entidades de mi aplicación están definiendo una propiedad con el mismo nombre 'Active' definido en 'BaseModelActive'
Este es el error completo que me arroja al intentar crear una nueva migración de EF
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Active
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.AddSeedData(IEntityType entityType, Dictionary`2 identityMaps, EntityState initialState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.TrackData(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDataOperations(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Migrations.Internal.MySqlMigrationsModelDiffer.PostFilterOperations(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Migrations.Internal.MySqlMigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Migrations.Internal.MySqlMigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Active

Alguien sabe debido a que se puede generar este error al haber actualizado la versión 8.0 de .NET?

Falto el titulo, pero genial...

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!
